# conda env create with file ignore default_packages in .condarc

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm trying to create new conda envoironment with a supplied `environment.yml` file looks like that:

```
name: myenv
dependencies:
  - bokeh
  - pandas
```

I have a `.condarc` file in my `$HOME` directory that has the following configurations:

```
create_default_packages:
  - ipykernel
  - papermill
channels:
  - conda-forge
```

when I run `conda env create --file environment.yml` I end up missing the default dependencies.
if I ran the same command without the file, `coda env create -n myenv` it will install the default packages.

is there a way to make it work with both environment file and install default dependencies?

conda info:

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : /airflow/.condarc
 populated config files : /airflow/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /opt/conda  (read only)
```

Comment: This seems like something that is either a bug, or by design. You should probably file an issue on the conda GitHub repository. The simple fix is to copy the files from the `.condarc` into the `.yaml` file.

Comment: This seems to me to be a rather unfortunate bug.The similar command "conda create" can take a requirements file AND consider the .condarc file. Very helpful to separate package requirements from individual developer preferences when setting up an environment. We use conda create rather than conda env create for that reason. What we lose is that conda create does not understand .yml (where you can specify pip installs) and we have to use a second step for pip installs that conda cannot perform. Both methods are deficient for different reasons and should be consolidated and fixed in my view.